# How does $\lim\limits_{Re(s)\rightarrow -\infty} Li_s(e^{w})$ become $\Gamma(1-s)(-w)^{s-1}$?

Tags: zeta-functions, polylogarithm

I am trying to prove the following property of polylogarithm. $$\lim\limits_{Re(s)\rightarrow -\infty} Li_s(e^{w}) = \Gamma(1-s)(-w)^{s-1} \text{ for } -\pi < \Im(w) < \pi.$$
As per Wikipedia's ["Polylogarithm" entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm#Relationship_to_other_functions), the above limit follows from the relationship of polylogarithm with Hurwitz-Zeta function as given below.
$$\displaystyle \operatorname {Li}_{s}(z)={\Gamma (1-s) \over (2\pi )^{1-s}}\left[i^{1-s}~\zeta \left(1-s,~{\frac {1}{2}}+{\ln(-z) \over {2\pi i}}\right)+i^{s-1}~\zeta \left(1-s,~{\frac {1}{2}}-{\ln(-z) \over {2\pi i}}\right)\right]$$ 
How do I observe this? Also is the above limit uniform for all $w$ by any chance?

Comment: $\lim_{s\to +\infty} a^{s} \zeta(s,a) = 1$ and your first line is an equivalent $\sim$ not a limit, and did you mean $Li_s(e^{-w})$ instead of $Li_s(e^w)$

Comment: Yes, I too understand it as the behaviour of $Li_s(e^w)$ for large enough $-Re(s)$ value. The wikipedia entry states the formula (1) as I had quoted here. It says $Li_s(e^w)$. I will try with your hint.

Comment: By uniform limit, what I wanted to know is: Suppose both $s$ and $w$ are variables, then in the asymptotic $Li_s(e^w) \sim \Gamma(1-s)(-w)^{s-1}$ for  $-\Re(s) \geq \sigma_0$, is the choice of $\sigma_0$ independent of $w$?

Comment: @reuns: could you give your comment on my last query?